# Google Business Profile API Real-Time Notifications Issue

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm facing an issue with real-time notifications not being received for new reviews on my Google Business Profile account, despite following the official documentation (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup). I'd appreciate any assistance in resolving this matter.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Enabled Cloud Pub/Sub Service and Created a Topic: Topic name:
   Locom-Testing (default settings)
2. Subscription name: Locom-Sub (push delivery type with mention endpoint)
3. Granted pubsub.topics.publish Permission
4. Linked Google Business Account to the Topic Using the REST API:-

Followed the code snippet provided in the documentation

```
    const apiUrl = `https://mybusinessnotifications.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/{account_id}/notificationSetting?updateMask=notificationTypes`;

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: `accounts/${payload.account.id}/notificationSetting`,
        pubsubTopic: 'projects/locom-app/topics/Locom-Testing',
        notificationTypes: ['NEW_REVIEW'],
      }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log(await response.json());
      return true;
    }

    const errorResponse = await response.json();
    throw new Error(errorResponse.error.message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      'Error: Reviews API function SubscribeReviewNotifications() throws error: ' +
        error
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

Verified API Response:-
The API response confirmed the successful update with notificationTypes set to ["NEW_REVIEW"].
`{"name": "accounts/115781*******74374531/notificationSetting", "notificationTypes": ["NEW_REVIEW"]}`
​

**Expected Behavior:**

- Upon receiving a new review, a message should be delivered to the subscriber (Locom-Sub)
  on the topic (Locom-Testing).
- When querying notification settings using the GET API, the response should include the
  linked topic.

**Actual Behavior:**

- No messages are received by the subscriber, even after new reviews are posted.
- The GET API response remains identical to the initial update response, showing
  notificationTypes set to ["NEW_REVIEW"] but not including the linked topic.

**Additional Information:**
I attempted using a query parameter (updateMask) to update both notificationTypes and pubsubTopic in a single request, but it resulted in an error.

**Request for Assistance:**
I'm seeking guidance from the community to troubleshoot this issue and ensure real-time notification delivery for new reviews.
Any insights, suggestions, or similar experiences would be highly valuable.

Comment: Since your question is quite clearly GPT generated, you should know that [AI generated content is currently banned from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).